# Rolling motion in space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Is rolling motion possible in space?

If so,

Let's imagine that two cylinders of different masses and inertias were rolled over an incline in space is it the case that the one with lower inertia will reach further as the later? Or they will also reach the same distance along each other as in earth?

The core of my question is mass always irrelevant to velocity in rolling motion or is it a "gravity" special case?

Comment: Is space important for the lack of air resistance, or do you mean in a microgravity environment (like on orbit).

Comment: I want to know if mass' irrelevance to velocity has something exceptional to do under gravity or it is always like that. It could be similar to that in the microgravity region.

Comment: How are they being "rolled over an incline"?  What force is being applied to them, and for how long?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My conclusion: Acted upon by the same force gravity or any other, two objects even with different masses and inertias will move at the same velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling motion is not only possible in space, but it's even highly likely. If you throw an object in a space that's absent of any significant gravitational field, assuming of course the object is not a theoretical "point mass", it will in general always undergo two motions: a linear one due to the force applied on its center of mass, and a rotational one in which all its parts revolve around its own center of mass. The latter will only be absent in the special case where there was no torque *at all* applied in the initial throw. Anyone who threw a ball knows that's a bit tricky: even if you do your best to avoid giving the ball a spin, you will still see it slightly rotating due to the "inhomogeneity" of the initial force which leads to a net torque.

It's not very clear how you would roll an object on an inclined plane where there is no gravity. However, if your question is basically about whether the moment of inertia still affects the rotational speed, the answer is undoubtedly **yes**. If you throw a rod in such a situation and it begins rotating, and now you imagine that you can order this rod to shorten by pressing a button on a remote, you will see the shortened rod rotating faster. So the angular speed is definitely dependent on its moment of inertia, which is a consequence of [conservation of angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Conservation_of_angular_momentum). And since the moment of inertia depends both on the geometry of the object *and on its mass*, then no, the speed of rolling is not independent of mass, and the same is true under the influence of gravity.

I know that there is a slight confusion sometimes about the moment of inertia and rolling speed: there is a popular demonstration of two cylinders of equal mass but different mass distributions, and it is shown that due to their different moments of inertia there will still be one that reaches the bottom of an inclined plane before the other. This can lead to a misunderstanding that mass does not affect the moment of inertia. But mass does: both the mass and the mass distribution are factors in determining the moment of inertia. If we can model our object by $n$ mass particle each one of mass $m_i$ which is some distance $r_i$ away from the center of mass then the moment of inertia $I$ is given by:

$$I = \sum_{i=1}^n{m_{i}r_{i}^2} $$

And if our object now has some angular momentum $L$ then the relation with its angular speed $\omega$ is:

$$ \omega = \frac{L}{I} $$

Which in particular explains why when we shortened our rod, angular speed had to increase: $\omega$ must increase to compensate for the decrease in $I$ (which occurs due to a decrease in our $r_i$'s), in order to conserve $L$.

Answer (score 0):

*I assume by space you really mean microgravity*.

For something to roll you need friction, and friction is generated by contact forces that are perpendicular to the contacting surfaces.

So a device might push on these cylinders against the ramp and achieve rolling, just like a cam-roller situation.

But if left on their own there is nothing to motive these rollers to move at all, and hence nothing to make them roll on surface.

Comment: Let's imagine that they're spun and pushed. Does the pushing-spinning force substitute for gravity's, causing mass to be yet again irrelevant to velocity? I think yes, they'll move equally since they're pushed with an equal force.